# What is the different between the two sql codes?

Tags: sql, exists

1.

```
select course_id
from course
where exists 
    (select course_id
    from course
    where course_id not in 
        (select course_id
        from section));
```

2.

```
select course_id
from course
where course_id not in 
    (select course_id
    from section);
```

I want to retrieve every `course_id` in table `course` that does not appear in table `section`. The first results in 200; The second results in 115.
Why the two have different result?

I interpret the first that I will check whether there is `course_id` in `course` that does not belong to `section`. If exists return true, then `course_id` that were checked before is the `course_id` chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs:

```
If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE
```

So in Your case, 1st query returns all rows casue it will looks like

```
select course_id from course where TRUE;
```

So if You want to retrieve every course_id in table course that does not appear in table section Your second query is correct.

And about that:

> I interpret the first that I will check whether there is course_id in course that does not belong to section. If exists return true, then course_id that were checked before is the course_id chosen.

This is wrong interpretation:
[Reference to docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your first query simply returns all courses, as 115 courses always `EXIST` that are not in section table. Therefore, the `EXIST` clause is always true.

Just to show the difference, the following query should return 115 rows as your second one. But your second one is certainly more efficient.

```
select c1.course_id
from course c1
where exists 
    (select c2.course_id
    from course c2
    where c1.course_id = c2.course_id
      and c2.course_id not in 
        (select course_id
        from section));
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/248a62/2).

Answer (score 0):

The explanation by @X.L.Ant is nice. Also you can do what you need this way:

```
select 
    course_id
from course
except all -- just exclude all id's from second select
select 
    course_id
from section
```